# Outputting LaTeX command from Lua script

Tags: lua, latex, tex

I am trying to use a Lua script to generate LaTeX commands. Here is a minimal lua script:

```
my_array = {
  cmdone = {1, 2},
  cmdtwo = {2, 3}
}

cmd_template = "\\newcommand*{\\%s}{number one: %s, number two: %s}"

function mkcommands()
  for k, v in pairs(my_array) do
    -- print(string.format(cmd_template, k, v[1], v[2]))
    tex.print(string.format(cmd_template, k, v[1], v[2]))
  end
end
```

And here is the TeX file:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
dofile("test.lua")
mkcommands()
\end{luacode}

%\newcommand*{\cmdtwo}{number one: 2, number two: 3}
%\newcommand*{\cmdone}{number one: 1, number two: 2}

\begin{document}

\cmdone

\cmdtwo

\end{document}
```

When I run `lualatex test.tex`, I get `Undefined control sequence l. 15 \cmdone`.

What am I doing wrong? Can this even be done?

I used the commented "print" command in the lua code to show that what was being generated looked correct. I then pasted the generated `\newcommand` commands into the TeX file to verify that they were working--producing the expected output

```
number one: 1, number two: 2 number one: 2, number two: 3
```

But it seems the `print()` and `tex.print` commands are producing different output.

Comment: Doesn't `%` start a comment in latex?

Comment: @shingo: Yes, but as this is an external Lua file, it gets no TeX processing. So Lua does the %s replacements before LuaLaTeX ever sees this string.

Comment: I meant the `%` before `\newcommand` in your tex file.

Comment: Right. Sorry. The commented lines in both files just show where I did tests: printing the output from the Lua file and pasting it into the tex file. The commands worked when pasted in but not when sent via tex.print().

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my problem was scope. When I used Lua to generate `\newcommand` commands inside a `\begin{luacode} ... \end{luacode}` environment, those commands disappeared when the environment ended. The fix was to use `\directlua` instead of the environment. With the same Lua file, this TeX file works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{luacode}

\directlua{dofile("test.lua")
mkcommands()}

\begin{document}

\cmdone

\cmdtwo

\end{document}
```